# How do I sequentially and nonparallel loop through an array in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

I have a list of objects i need to send to a server and i would like to do this one after the other (not in parallel). After all objects have been sent and there was no error i want to run additional Observables which do different things.

```swift
let objects = [1, 2, 3]

let _ = Observable.from(objects).flatMap { object -> Observable<Void> in
    return Observable.create { observer in
        print("Starting request \(object)")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { // one request takes ~2sec
            print("Request \(object) finished")
            observer.onNext(Void())
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}.flatMap { result -> Observable<Void> in
    print("Do something else (but only once)")
    return Observable.just(Void())
}.subscribe(
    onNext: {
        print("Next")
    },
    onCompleted: {
        print("Done")
    }
)
```

What i get is

```
Starting request 1
Starting request 2
Starting request 3
Request 1 finished
Do something else (but only once)
Next
Request 2 finished
Do something else (but only once)
Next
Request 3 finished
Do something else (but only once)
Next
Done
```

The whole process ends after 2 sec. What i want is

```
Starting request 1
Request 1 finished
Starting request 2
Request 2 finished
Starting request 3
Request 3 finished
Do something else (but only once)
Next
Done
```

The whole sequence should end after 6 seconds (because it's not executed parallel).

I got this to work with a recursive function. But with lots of requests this ends in a deep recursion stack which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` in order to send them one at a time instead of all at once. Learn more here:

[RxSwift’s Many Faces of FlatMap](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)

Then to do something just once afterwards, use `toArray()`. Here is a complete example:

```
let objects = [1, 2, 3]

_ = Observable.from(objects)
    .concatMap { object -> Observable<Void> in
        return Observable.just(())
            .debug("Starting Request \(object)")
            .delay(.seconds(2), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .debug("Request \(object) finished")
    }
    .toArray()
    .flatMap { results -> Single<Void> in
        print("Do something else (but only once)")
        return Single.just(())
    }
    .subscribe(
        onSuccess: { print("done") },
        onError: { print("error", $0) }
    )
```

Comment: Strange, thought i tried concatMap too, but that is indeed the solution, thank you! Do you also have an idea for the second part running one task after concatMap completes? Now i get "Do something else..." after each request...